# What is the best way to work with static variables in java/c++/c/actionscript-3 applications?

Tags: java, c++, c, actionscript-3

I'm working on an application where I am using static variables (eg: the pixel width of a tile, or how many tiles I want in an array).

I have them currently declared in the class that defines the object, for example tileWidth is in TileClass. I am using this width in multiple other classes, and I am bugged by the fact that i have to import the whole Tile class just to access this field. Is there any performance loss by this?

Is it better practice to hold all static variables (they are actually constants) in a separate class and just import that whenever I need the variable?

Is there other better way than using static variables?

Thanks

Comment: C++ and Java are too different here to give a general answer IMHO

Comment: And C is again quite different since it has no classes. I can't make much sense of your question in that context.

Comment: Consider using a singleton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it better practice to hold all static variables (they are actually constants) in a separate class and just import that whenever I need the variable?

Just put all the constants in an `Interface` and reference them using that Interface. There is no performance impact as such put it is just good design rather that creating a class for constants and making them public static (as variables defines in an Interface are implicitly `public default and static`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a performance impact as your application loads your class holding the static variables only once. 
Also, always ensure that your static variables are `final`, if you don't want modification on them.